# Does this question belong on this site?

Tags: discussion

Does this question belong on this site?

[Rovelli's preferred emergent frame - A new stance on "Newton's bucket vs Leibniz relationals"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91064/rovellis-preferred-emergent-frame-a-new-stance-on-newtons-bucket-vs-leibniz?noredirect=1#comment255616_91064)

The commenter seems think not? I personally found the line of distinction quite blurry. But I would gladly comply with rules.

Cheers